# How would you parse an IP address from a string of characters in C?

Tags: c, parsing, ip

I have a variable that holds these sets of characters:

```
char recvBuff[1024] = "OK lastname,firstname 127.0.0.1";
```

I'm trying to parse the `127.0.0.1` IP address from that entire string and assign it to another variable. How can I parse this IP address from the string?
(I don't need 127, 0, 0, and 1 separate. I need "127.0.0.1" as a whole string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing ip adress string in 4 single bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211601/parsing-ip-adress-string-in-4-single-bytes)

Comment: `sscanf` is your friend...

Comment: @sashoalm these are two different questions. I need the entire IP address. Not the 4 bytes individually. Thank you though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` function to separate the string.

```
      char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

      char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
```

Before separating the string You can take the backup of the string because it will affect the original string.

Comment: perfect, thank you. i had to create a token `char *token` then type the same line three times to get to the IP address `token = strtok(recvBuff, " ");` (at this point the token is at the OK characters, then `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` (the token is now the lastname,firstname) and finally do the same thing one more time to make the token equal to the IP address. 

Is there a way to simplify this?

Comment: Are you using `"OK lastname,firstname 127.0.0.1"` string only or you will have some other strings and at last `address`?